# How do you craft a cake?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

A Minecraft update is coming today with cake included. I know which ingredients are likely to be involved, but not how to place them. So, how do you craft cake?

Comment: If the update isn't out yet then let me know as soon as you can. I don't have a PC with Minecraft on it right now to test it myself

Comment: North, one robot version of botticelli, north east a blue cloth, north west a green cloth, east a purple cloth, west a furnace, south a rocket launcer and center a portal gun. Maybe throw buttons southwest and southeast, but make sure they're properly powered.

Comment: The cake is a lie!

Comment: It's a piece of cake to bake a pretty cake. If the way is hazy,
you gotta do the cooking by the book (you know you can't be lazy). Never use a messy recipe; the cake will end up crazy. If you do the cooking by the book, then you'll have a **cake**.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Specifically the recipe for cake is [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cake).

[image]

Top: 3 milk

Middle: 1 sugar, 1 egg, 1 sugar

Bottom: 3 wheat

Comment: Output is reportedly six uses of 1.5 hearts each.

Answer (score 2):

You need two sugar canes to make two sugar,
you need three wheats,
an egg,
And three pails of milk which you need three buckets to collect the milk,
It takes three iron to make one bucket,
[This site](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cake) shows you how to craft everything.

Answer (score 1):

Notch had a tweet on January 10th:

The recipe for cake is milk*3 + sugar*2 +egg*1 + wheat*3. Of course. (You will get the buckets for the milk back)

Comment: Also, reeds/bamboo are now sugar canes. (They have always been sugar canes. We just didn't know until now.)

Comment: He considered adding eggs, so that may have well changed. Can you test in-game and post a picture?

Comment: This is incorrect. It has an egg in the centre too. See indyK1ng's answer.